# При конвертации XML в CSV сохраняется пустой файл

Tags: xml, excel, vba

**Программа отлично работает с .xls , но не с .xml**

**Задача**: найти файлы ПИРОЖОК с расширением .xml и конвертировать отредактированный файл в .csv.

**Проблема**: У меня всё работает, конвертирует, сохраняет. Но вот условия, где ему говорю убирать пробелы, удалять пустые строки - не работают. Он мне из файла с таблицами сохраняет пустой .csv.

```
    'find the xml files in the directory
If Not curfold Is Nothing Then
    For Each fil In curfold.Files
        If InStr(1, fil.Name, ".xml", vbTextCompare) > 0 and (InStr(1, fil.Name, "PIE", vbTextCompare)) > 0 Then
            d = fil.Name
            Set wb = objEX.Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & d)

            If InStr(1, fil.Name, "PIE", vbTextCompare) > 0  Then
                'remove the spaces from the amounts
                wb.Sheets(1).Columns("C:C").NumberFormat = "0.00"
                wb.Sheets(1).Columns("D:D").NumberFormat = "0.00"

                'replace"; /" on " ."
                wb.Sheets(1).Range("K1").value=wb.Sheets(1).Range("K1").value & ";"
                wb.Sheets(1).Range("A:K").Replace ";", " "

                wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").value=wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").value & "/"
                wb.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Replace "/", "."
                '   wb.Sheets(1).Range("H:H").Replace " ", ""       

                'delete empty lines
                wb.Sheets(1).Rows("1:3").Delete
                su=1

                'delete column L and M
                wb.Sheets(1).Columns("M:M").delete
                wb.Sheets(1).Columns("L:L").delete

                nRow = 1
                'delete the extra empty lines at the end of the file
                Do While wb.Sheets(1).Cells(nRow, 1).Value <> ""  
                    nRow = nRow + 1
                loop
                wb.Sheets(1).Rows(nRow & ":" & nRow+20000).Delete
```

Comment: vbs => (xml + xsl) = csv, используя vbs сценарий, можно загрузить две xml (точнее xml и xsl), затем сделать вызов Transform - и на выходе будет готовый csv. Кода думаю будет гораздо меньше, и наличие excel не обязательно. Если требуется такая автоматизация - почитайте xsl http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL

Comment: Прошу прощения, я новичок в этом. Не мог бы показать на коде как будет выглядеть? Не совсем понимаю как вызвать xml и xsl, как сделано у меня, где я открываю файл?

Comment: У меня в целом конвертирует файл, проблема в том, что в сохранённом файле абсолютно ничего нет, он пустой, хотя должен иметь определённые столбцы и строки и отформатирован в соответствии с тем, как указано в коде.

Comment: Вы знакомы с таким словом - трассировка? вот и трассируйте, смотрите, как меняются значения переменных и ячеек таблицы, и что на самом деле пишется в файл, если вообще что-то пишется...

Comment: Возможно ли, что ошибка заключается в том, что программный код, который есть - не может записывать/изменить данные в файле формата .xml и работает только на .xls? Мне кажется, что нужно в коде добавить конвертер из .xml в .xls и дальше уже работать с .xls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конвертер из .xml в .csv

```
Try this code

Sub XMLTOCSV()
Dim f           As String
Dim p           As String
Dim s           As Integer

p = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads" & "\"
f = Dir(p & "*.xml")
s = 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        s = s + 1
        ConvertXMLtoCSV p & f, p & "Test" & s & ".csv"
        f = Dir()
    Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub ConvertXMLtoCSV(xmlFile, csvFile)
Dim xlApp       As Application
Dim xlBook      As Workbook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.OpenXML(xmlFile, 2)
xlBook.SaveAs csvFile, 6
xlBook.Close False
xlApp.Quit
End Sub
```

Способ, чтобы назвать .csv файлы точно так же, как оригинал .XML

```
ConvertXMLtoCSV p & f, p & Replace(f, ".xml", "") & ".csv"
```